# Vagrant and cups port forwarding not working. Not accessible

Tags: linux, vagrant, cups

I'm working with vagrant and I'm trying to use it as a printing server. I installed cups.

Internally everything works just fine. I can even make a quick `curl` to my localhost:631 (cups port inside my vagrant) and there's everything.

The thing is I can't access it in any way I try from the host machine.

Obviously I forwarded the port and I've tried with several ports. I've also tried with Debian squeeze and Ubuntu 12.04. Here is my current `Vagrantfile`

```
Vagrant.configure("2") do |config|                                              
  config.vm.box = "guruDebian"
  config.vm.network :forwarded_port, guest: 80, host: 8080
  config.vm.network :forwarded_port, guest: 631, host: 6363   ## HERE IS CUPS           
end
```

Any ideas? ... I'll upload any file if necessary.

Comment: Solved the problem in [this link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19571708/vagrant-port-forwarding-not-working-cups-not-accesible-from-host/19585109?noredirect=1#19585109)